# Is it possible to use the class defined in another cpp file rather than any header?

Tags: c++, shared-libraries, static-libraries, extern

There is a C++ class that has been compiled into a library but I have access to its source code; however since the class isn't defined in any header file I cannot simply include and then link the libray. I don't would like to change the library source code, but I hope to utilize the class functions for me, is it possible?

Maybe `extern` will help, but I just don't the proper syntax.

Comment: Create a header file with a copy of the class definition. Include it as necessary.

Comment: If you are using an external library and the class you want to use is not propagated by headers then it is surely not intended for you to use it since it is just some internal stuff.
If you know what you are doing then follow Igor's advise.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik So I should copy **ALL** the class definition(its definition of the variable and its declaration of the function members) exactly rather than the member function I really need?

Comment: Yes, you must copy the complete definition exactly. Otherwise, the two modules won't agree on the size and memory layout of class instances.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik: I think you're mixing up "definition" and "declaration".

Comment: @Beta: No I do not. This is class declaration: `class X;`. This is class definition: `class X {int n; void f(); };`.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik: ...You're right. I've been using the terminology wrong all these years.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not possible [or at least not a good idea] to do this without "moving" the class declaration to a header-file that is used by both the library and your application.

Of course, it's technically possible to add the class declaration to your .cpp file (or some header-file), but this is not very reliable, because someone may change the class in the library code, and then you have an incompatible class declaration, which is "undefined behaviour" - meaning your code will often do something OTHER than what you wanted it to do.

Of course, the fact that the class is not in a header seems to imply that it's "for internal use only".

Comment: To change the source code and rebuild the library requires a header file. Who is going to do that -- anonymously -- and not leave the header file with the new library? Will he leave some token behind, like a monogrammed glove, or a rose cut in two?

Comment: @Beta: That sounds like "source code mangement". Obviously, it depends quite a lot on where the source came from and who owns the rights to it, whether this is something that can be done. My point is that if there isn't an external declaration of the class, then if a new version of the library is used, the class could well be different, and that would cause problems - I'm not thinking of sneaky ninja-programmers here.

Comment: If the OP is using this code as a shared resource, but cannot communicate with the person who changed the library and get access to the header file, then there is evil afoot; either a ninja programmer who codes by night, or monumentally inept project management... you're right, it's not a ninja programmer.